# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

Can you explain me why does this happen and how can I fix it please?

So I'm using Oracle-ADF and I'm using shuttle components. I get the selected values using the `sos1.getValue();`

The getValue() method returns an object and I'm trying to convert it to an ArrayList so I can work with it later. Therefore I've created the `ArrayList sos1Value`

However, this line of code is going bananas:

```
sos1Value = (ArrayList) Arrays.asList(sos1.getValue());
```

And I keep getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList`

I've tried other ways like: `sos1Value = (ArrayList) sos1.getValue();`

But I keep having the same problem, what can I do?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns a `List` implementation, but it's not a `java.util.ArrayList`. It happens to have a classname of `ArrayList`, but that's a nested class within `Arrays` - a completely different type from `java.util.ArrayList`.

If you *need* a `java.util.ArrayList`, you can just create a copy:

```
ArrayList<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(sos1.getValue());
```

If you *don't* need an ArrayList just remove the cast:

```
List<Foo> list = Arrays.asList(sos1.getValue());
```

(if you don't need any members exposed just by `ArrayList`).

Comment: Why not assign it to a `List` directly?.

Comment: @AlexisC.: Sorry, meant to do that :)

Comment: @TheLostMind: Not sure what you mean - the declared type of `list`?

Comment: You've added it - `List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(sos1.getValue()); ` :)

Comment: @TheLostMind: Righto.

Comment: `new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList(new String[] { "hey", "yo"}))` would also work

Comment: @AbSin The inner `new String[] { }` is redundant. The `asList(String...)` method implicitly allocates such a string array, without you needing to explicitly spell it out.

Comment: @JonSkeet What's the motivation behind having a separate `ArrayList` class? Why couldn't the implementation do something like `return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList(array));`?

Comment: @Alexander: That would copy the array, rather than providing a view over it. They behave very differently.

Answer (score 9):

`Arrays.asList(sos1.getValue());` produces an instance of a List implementation (`java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`) that is not java.util.ArrayList. Therefore you can't cast it to `java.util.ArrayList`.

If you change the type of `sos1Value` to `List`, you won't need this cast.

If you must have an instance of `java.util.ArrayList`, you can create it yourself :

```
sos1Value = new ArrayList (Arrays.asList(sos1.getValue()));
```

Comment: how can I fix it then?

Answer (score 8):

The `ArrayList` returned by `Arrays.asList()` method is NOT `java.util.ArrayList` it is a static inner class inside `Arrays` class. So, you can't cast it to `java.util.ArrayList`.

Try converting / assigning it to a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way (not efficient) is

```
ArrayList sos2Value = new ArrayList()
sos2Value.addAll(Arrays.asList(sos1.getValue()))
```

sos2Value is java.util.ArrayList.
Arrays.asList(sos1.getValue()) is java.util.Arrays$ArrayList

But I'm not clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I used it in this way:

```
 private fun getArtists(): ArrayList<ArtistItem> {
        var xp = myDb.daoNote().getArtists() as ArrayList<ArtistItem>
        val x: List<ArtistItem> =  xp.sortedWith(compareBy { it.isBookmarked})
        var pp = ArrayList<ArtistItem>()
        for(obj in x)
        {
            pp.add(obj)
        }

     return pp
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Eclipse IDE then just make a your package and under that package create java file,it will work.

Answer (score -1):

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

You need to set the type to java.util.List