# What do these error messages mean? (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am writing a GUI thing that allows someone to automatically organize their students into groups. So far, I've gotten to the point where I type in the students and click a button to set them. However, when I click the button I get a whole bunch of errors.

Here is the code I have, so far:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class StudentGrouper extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    private static ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    StudentGrouper frame = new StudentGrouper();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public StudentGrouper() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        contentPane.add(tabbedPane);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Enter Students", null, scrollPane, null);

        JTextPane txtpnOneStudentPer = new JTextPane();
        txtpnOneStudentPer.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        txtpnOneStudentPer.setText("One student per line...");
        scrollPane.setViewportView(txtpnOneStudentPer);

        JButton btnSetStudentList = new JButton("Set Student List");
        btnSetStudentList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                students = (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(txtpnOneStudentPer.getText().split("\n"));
                System.out.println(students.get((int)(Math.random() * students.size())));
            }
        });
        btnSetStudentList.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(btnSetStudentList);

        JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Select Students", null, scrollPane_1, null);
    }

}
```

Here are the error messages I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at StudentGrouper$2.actionPerformed(StudentGrouper.java:65)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Can anyone tell me what's causing these errors to occur?

(Obviously, I am guessing, the errors stem from one minor error that I skipped over in a hurry. Please tell me!)

Comment: Read the exception. It says `ClassCastException` on line 65. Look at line 65: `students = (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(txtpnOneStudentPer.getText().split("\n"));` The class-cast here is `(ArrayList<String>)`. According to the exception message, `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` is different from `java.util.ArrayList`. Now, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28851652/5645656) where someone had the *exact same problem*, and see if you can figure out the solution without someone straight up telling you. That way you will better remember the solution.

Comment: Why do you believe that `Arrays.asList()` returns an `ArrayList`, when the method is explicitly defined to return a `List`? Anyway, you are obviously *mistaken* in your belief, as evident by the error message.

Comment: Keep in mind that `Arrays#asList` returns a _fixed-sized_ list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are initializing your `students` with `ArrayList<String>` but your `Arrays.asList` does not create the "same" `ArrayList` type. Just use the interface instead to make sure you can easily switch between list-types:

```
private static List<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

That way you can remove the cast and it works:

```
students = Arrays.asList(txtpnOneStudentPer.getText().split("\n"));
```